# NestJS deserializing @Query() to a DTO with complex types

Tags: node.js, typescript, query-string, nestjs, dto

Whilst studying NestJS I encountered an issue, I have the following DTO:

```
export default class SearchNotesDto {
  query: string;
  createdAfter: Date;
  createdBefore: Date;
}
```

Which I wish to get when a `GET` request is made to an endpoint, which is handled by the following function in my controller:

```
@Get()
getNotes(@Query() searchNotesDto: SearchNotesDto): Note[] {
  if (Object.keys(searchNotesDto).length) {
    return this.notesService.searchNotes(searchNotesDto);
  }
  return this.notesService.getAllNotes();
}
```

My problem is that `createdAfter` and `createdBefore` are strings in `searchNotesDto`, and I wish to work with the `Date` object, is there a way to implicitly convert those fields to a `Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Query` will serialize all properties to type `string` because that's how query string works in terms of HTTP Request. You will need to utilize a `Pipe` to transform your query to the right shape of data.

https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes

```js
export class SearchNotePipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
      // value will be your `searchNotesDto`
      const notesDto = new SearchNotesDto();
      // do your transformation here
      return notesDto;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am aware that query string is a *string*, I was just looking for a clean way to handle serialization and pipes were the way - thanks!